# Parse.com Chaining Promises in Series

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise, chaining

I am trying to take a list of photo objects and assign them to galleries based upon the date they were taken.  The trick is that before the process executes, there may be no galleries at all (i.e. - the code needs to generate a new gallery for a day that doesn't have one when it comes across a photo taken on that day).

Here is my code:

```
var Photo = Parse.Object.extend("Photo");
var Gallery = Parse.Object.extend("Gallery");

var query = new Parse.Query(Photo);
query.equalTo("owner", Parse.User.current());

query.find().then(function(results) {

    // Create a trivial resolved promise as a base case.
    var promise = Parse.Promise.as();

    for (photo in results)
    {
       var photoObject = results[photo];

       //Closure to encapsulate the photo object represented by this loop iteration
       //(function(photo) {
       promise = promise.then((function(photo) {
            console.log('iterator: ' + photo.id);
            var takenAt = photo.get("takenAt");

            var dd = takenAt.getDate();
            var mm = takenAt.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!`

            var yyyy = takenAt.getFullYear();

            var dateOf = new Date(yyyy+"-"+mm+"-"+dd);

            var query = new Parse.Query(Gallery);
            query.equalTo("owner", Parse.User.current());
            query.equalTo("dateOf", dateOf);

            query.find().then(function(galleries) {

              console.log("Galleries:"+galleries.length);

              if (galleries.length > 0)
              {
                 photo.addUnique("galleries",galleries[0]);
                 photo.save();
              }
              else
              {
                 var gallery = new Gallery();
                 gallery.set("owner",Parse.User.current());
                 gallery.set("dateOf",dateOf);

                 return gallery.save();
              }

            }).then(function(gallery) {
              //Finished new gallery save!
              photo.addUnique("galleries",gallery);
              photo.save();

            });

       })(photoObject));
    }

    return promise;

    //console.log(photo.get("takenAt"));
}).then(function() {
// Every photo was added to the proper gallery.
});
```

The problem is that when it runs, I get the following output (Running an Express/Node.js server on the backend and this is the console output):

```
I2014-10-03T19:08:24.934Z]iterator: bZJ1Ke0QXO
I2014-10-03T19:08:24.936Z]iterator: 6li2Ztxhrd
I2014-10-03T19:08:24.937Z]iterator: FfUCwgNsts
I2014-10-03T19:08:24.937Z]iterator: fJdAeqCwYW
I2014-10-03T19:08:24.939Z]iterator: ChUmgipm7d
I2014-10-03T19:08:24.942Z]iterator: 9MiTFHxLzh
I2014-10-03T19:08:24.942Z]iterator: bWZAbNiNB2
I2014-10-03T19:08:24.943Z]iterator: RQqe3NyAxK
I2014-10-03T19:08:24.991Z]Galleries:0
I2014-10-03T19:08:25.043Z]Galleries:0
I2014-10-03T19:08:25.045Z]Galleries:0
I2014-10-03T19:08:25.095Z]Galleries:0
I2014-10-03T19:08:25.146Z]Galleries:0
I2014-10-03T19:08:25.147Z]Galleries:0
I2014-10-03T19:08:25.253Z]Galleries:0
I2014-10-03T19:08:25.305Z]Galleries:0
```

So you can see that the first gallery being created happens after all photos have been checked, and the issue is that it creates 8 galleries for the same day (All photos in the sample set were taken on the same day).

It simply looks like the promises are not executing in series as I would have expected.  How can I force these calls to happen in sequence so the second photo lookup doesn't happen until the first has finished creating a Gallery (If it needs to)?

Comment: The way `then` knows how to wait for the next item is by using the return value - whenever you perform an async action - if you want to wait for it to be done you should `return` it.

Comment: That did it! Needed a couple other things to work inside the Parse framework, but that was the critical piece. You rock :)

Comment: For those that find this, the inner "query.find()" chained promises needed to be returned for it to properly track them.  Also, I incorporated the _.each() construct instead of the raw closure from above since the parse backend was giving a stack trace triggered by the closure (I don't know why).

Comment: That makes sense - the docs call it out too: "If the callback itself returns a Promise, then the one returned by "then" will not be fulfilled until that one returned by the callback is fulfilled."